# Locally redefining ~ in code that uses expl3 facilities

Tags: expl3

I am trying to rewrite a package to use expl3 facilities.

Here I need to define an `\initializeplaintitle` command that stores a "purified" version of the document title, retrieved from `\@title` into a macro.  The current (LaTeX2e) version is

```
\newcommand\initializeplaintitle[1][]{%
  {%
    \def\\{ }%
    \def~{ }%
    \def\emph##1{##1}%
    #1%
    \protected@xdef\plaintitle{\@title}%
  }%
}
```

As you can see, it makes some local assignments so that any `\\` and `~` present in the title become spaces and it strips out all `\emph` commands.

I wonder how I can obtain the same result in a package that is written using the expl3 syntax and facilities. In principle, the `\def` should become `\tl_set:Nn`. But how can I act on the `~` given that this is redefined in the expl3 syntax?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\char_set_active:nN`

```
\char_set_active:nN { `\~ } \c_space_tl
```

This gives a meaning to the character specified in the first argument in a context where it is active (which `~` is in normal situations).

You also have to condense spaces, so probably something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\title{A \emph{title} \\ about \emph{A.~Uthor}} % to initialize \@title

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_callegar_title_pure_tl
\tl_new:N \l__callegar_title_pure_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \callegar_purify_title:
 {
  \tl_set_eq:Nc \l__callegar_title_pure_tl { @title }
  % \emph{...} -> ...
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{emph}\cB. (.*?) \cE. } { \1 } \l__callegar_title_pure_tl
  % \\ and ~ -> space
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\c{\\}|\cA\~) } { \  } \l__callegar_title_pure_tl
  % multiple spaces to a single space
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \s+ } { \  } \l__callegar_title_pure_tl
  % globally set the purified title
  \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_callegar_title_pure_tl \l__callegar_title_pure_tl
 }

\callegar_purify_title:
\tl_show:N \g_callegar_title_pure_tl

\stop
```

The output will be

```
> \g_callegar_title_pure_tl=A title about A. Uthor.
```

Comment: The second solution using regexps is clear to me, even if not completely compatible with the previous version of my code (sorry, I failed to give you enough context --- the `#1` in the latex2e code that I gave you was meant to pass to the code other substitutions in the form of `\def`s as in `\initializeplaintitle{\def\extrainfo#1{}}`). I'll try to make some experiments with the  `\char_set_active:nN { \`\~ } \c_space_tl`  to see if I can work out another solution (even if the one with the regexps is much nicer and I plan to move to something like this later on).